# Does DatePciker auto detect locale to display date

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I know it is displaying US or British date Format?? What is the default dateformat?

Q1) How to I convert the date to local locale after detecting the phone is in non-US locale?
Q2) Which event to use after the user has entered the date and to do the conversion?

```
  <toolkit:DatePicker x:Name="beginDatePicker" Margin="0,300,0,0" Width="220" HorizontalAlignment="Left"> </toolkit:DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a locale. Just take the `Value` property, which will be a `DateTime`, and it should be fine. (What "kind" it will be - unspecified, UTC or local - I'm not sure, but that's another matter.)

I haven't used this particular control, but I'd certainly *expect* it to use the current thread's UI culture and examine the [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) property - then probably check the [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx) - in order to get the most appropriate format *for display / input*.

You should check what happens if you put the emulator/phone into different locales though.

Comment: after a few testing, indeed the default Date Format  of DatePicker is in US-Format : MM/DD/YYYY. I can force it to the format I want with this method:beginDatePicker.ValueStringFormat = beginDt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("fr-FR")) even the locale is in US.  Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle: Really? For sure? You don't have US users who will be confused by that? I would generally be very reticent to force a "foreign" locale setting on a user.

Comment: Allow me to correct my statement. The DatePicker will auto detect the locale. I change the WP7 emulator to Chinese, the date show will be in chinese format as well as the return date after selecting. Yes, I too can change the date format in the return Date from DatePicker to US-date format.